# Netbeans persistence I added new column to the database how package.persis's classes are generated

Tags: netbeans-7

I have a program on NetBeans already programmed by another programmer where he used the persistence on it.
This program is linked to the database.

I wanted to add a column in the database and show it in the NetBeans project. But this column shows "error", and the table in package.persis doesn't show me the new column that i added.

So how can I add the new column to the table? because I think there's a way to automatically create the classes of this package.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is: 
- right click the project 
- New - Entity Classes From database... 
- Database Tables 
- New Database Connection 
- I chose mysql 
- then i entered the database name and link and user and password 
- Next 
- Finish
- Here it will retrieve the tables from my Database

I followed the following link [ref link](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2008/07/totd_38_creatin.html) it really helped me